# BroadcastReceiver.onReceive not called, but Activity.onNewIntent do. Why?

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get "DeleteIntent" callback from my notification.
**BroadcastReceiver.onReceive** not called from PendengIntent, while it works OK when broadcast is launched manually with **sendBroadcast(deleteIntent)**.

It works well when intent target is **Activity** (hits **Activity.onNewIntent**) but it is weird to use it since activity goes foreground when message dismissed.

Please, help to get **onReceive** call to **BroadcastReceiver**.
It is visible, exported and enabled, located in the same package.

*MyCancelReceiver class*

```
public class MyCancelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

*Android manifest*

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">

<MyCancelReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="notification_cancelled"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

*MainActivity*

```
private MyCancelReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("notification_cancelled");
    mReceiver = new MyCancelReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();       
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

*Notification creation:*

```
Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyCancelReceiver.class);
cancelIntent.setAction("notification_cancelled");
cancelIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Notification not = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), Util.ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, not);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you start your activity, onStart() gets called and you will get a callback in onReceive() as soon as the activity is launched. But when you click your notification onStart won't be called as the activity is already created, In this case, onStart wont be called. Try registering in onResume(), I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Thank you.
But  as I can see BroadcastReceiver configured correctly. It works OK when broadcast is launched manually with **sendBroadcast**.

Comment: I dont this there is any problem with existing broadcast receiver,you just need to register at right place,while clicking your notification if onNewIntent gets called then register it there too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using an answer from this thread [Click on android notification icon does not trigger broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404778/click-on-android-notification-icon-does-not-trigger-broadcast-receiver?rq=1)

Explicit intent replaced with implicit one. 
    Intent cancelIntent = new Intent("notification_canceled");