# PendingIntent.getBoradcast broadcast receiver not called

Tags: android, foregroundnotification

I am trying to add a stop button to my foreground service notification, so I used a broadcast receiver. But when I click the stop button in notification nothings happens.

```kotlin
val stopIntent = Intent(this, StopBroadCastReceiver::class.java)
stopIntent.action = STOP_SERVICE
val stopPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 1, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

notification
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
    .setContentTitle("Pyrum is running...")
    .setSubText("192.168.1.67")
    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, getString(R.string.stop), stopPendingIntent)
    .priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build())
```

**broadcast receiver**

```kotlin
inner class StopBroadCastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("hello", "STOP!!!")
    }
}
```

It should log `STOP!!!` but it did nothing.

Comment: How exactly are you registering `StopBroadCastReceiver`?

Comment: I registered in the code like this. `registerReceiver(StopBroadCastReceiver(), IntentFilter(STOP_SERVICE))`

Comment: You would need to use an implicit `Intent` then; i.e., one that does not target the `StopBroadCastReceiver` class. To do that with the given code, you could simply change `Intent(this, StopBroadCastReceiver::class.java)` to `Intent()`. I should also mention that dynamically registering that Receiver might not be the best design for your setup. Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42405035) for more information.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I edited my comment above with a link to one of my answers for a similar question. You might have a read through that so you know what to expect. In fact, that's the exact same issue there, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate. Glad you got it working. Cheers!